# How would I go about getting the coordinates (Longitude & Latitude) of a single wikidata entity in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I would like to make a SPARQL query to the wikidata API, where I would get the coordinates (lat & long) of a particular entity such as Paris (Q90) if I'm not mistaken - although this seems relatively simple, I cannot for the life of me find the correct syntax! I would very much appreciate a little bit of help on this, as I am quite the SPARQL rookie :)

Comment: I know that I should somehow extract the P625 property, but cannot find the proper syntax...

Comment: I did actually find a way to do it using the API: if some are curious, here is the URL: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q90&property=P625

Comment: ok, you found a way via REST API, but the SPARQL query would be `select * {wd:Q90 wdt:P625 ?o}`

Comment: thank you very much AKSW! would you like to offer this as an answer so I can give you a green tick?